# Receiving one set of numbers with regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have info like the following

> "id":"456138988365628440_103920","user"657852231654

and I would like to return,

> 456138988365628440_103920

I know using

> "id":"[0-9_]*","user"

will return

> "id":"456138988365628440_103920","user"

but I just want the `id` itself.

Comment: Rephrase your question to make it more clear, remove `""` if it is not the part of string

Comment: Is it possible that your string is *json*?

Comment: If you need output as `id:456138988365628440_103920` then `id:[0-9_]+` should work. What's your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use capture groups by placing the part you want between parentheses and calling it back using `match.Groups[1].Value`:

```
string msg = @"""id"":""456138988365628440_103920"",""user""657852231654""";
var reg = new Regex(@"""id"":""([0-9_]*)"",""user""", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var results = reg.Matches(msg);
foreach (Match match in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/ncJuZU).

Answer (score 0):

Or you could just use [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (if regex are not mandatory):

```
var input = @"""id"":""456138988365628440_103920"",""user""657852231654""";
var idValue = input.Split(',')[0].Split(':')[1];
Console.WriteLine(idValue);
```

Output:

```
456138988365628440_103920
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a kind of conditional statement in your Regular Expression, which is called [`Zero-Width Positive Look-behind Assertion`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx#backreference_constructs)

In other words, you need a statement that says **only match numbers which are after the `id` property**.

"id":"456138988365628440_103920","user"657852231654

```
(?<="id":")[\d_]*
```

This regular expression would only return the requested number for you.

You can test it [here](http://regexhero.net/tester/).